# select a list of variable names from a CSV file in R or Python

Tags: python, r, csv

Does anyone know how to extract a list of variables from a CSV file? More specifically, I have a very large CSV file where each column is a variable and each row is an individual sample. I have a list of more than 100 variable names that I am interested in and want to extract only those from a list of more than 1000 variable in total. I want these variables for all the subjects (rows) of the data. The original file was in an SPSS file format but I thought it would be easier to select the variable if I converted the file to csv.  What is the best way to do this?

Here is an example:

```
SDYID  b_t  cd_t  cf_t  cu_t  en_t  fu_t  ip_t  ft_t  tc_t  lo_t
subj1  2.8  2.7   2.5   1.8   3.2   2.8   2.5   2.7   2.4   2.9
subj2  2.9  2.1   2.3   1.9   3.4   2.6   2.6   2.8   2.5   3.1
```

So, for example I would like to extract variables **cf_t** and **tc_t** for all the subjects and save it in another csv file:

```
SDYID  cf_t tc_t
subj1  2.5  2.4  
subj2  2.3  2.5
```

I have the variable names that I would like to extract in text file. The actual file contains many more variables and subjects.

Thanks a lot,
-Moj

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: You might like `csv.DictReader()`

Comment: Not clear from the comments.  Please consider to edit your post with the expectations and input

Comment: Are the variable names expressed as column names in the csv header (the first row)? You could use python `pandas.read_csv("myfile.csv", usecols=["list", "of", "names"])` which would automatically discard the variables you don't want. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv

Comment: In R, common data reading functions like `readr::read_csv` and `data.table::fread` let you specify which columns you want by name or number. You can see their help pages for examples.

Comment: [csvcut](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvcut.html) from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this is to use the `readr` package from the larger `tidyverse` family of packages in `R`. In particular, when using the `read_csv()` function from `readr` one can specify the `col_select` argument to read those desired columns (variables) into `R`. See an example below.

I also use `base` and the `here` package to assist in creating, finding, and writing the example data to an Excel file.

```
library(here)
library(readr)
write.csv(data.frame(a=rep(1:10),b=rep(1:10),cf_t=rep(1:10),
                     tc_t=rep(1:10),d=rep(1:10)),
          file=here("data.csv"),row.names = FALSE)
data<-read_csv(here("data.csv"),col_select = c(3,4))
write.csv(data,file=here("newdata.csv"),row.names = FALSE)
```

The package `readr` has many more useful functions and arguments, which are described at https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html. You may also be interested in `dplyr` when you need to clean the data you are selectively reading into `R`, which is described at https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/.